# how to constantly check if iframe contain specified class or id

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

So let's just say i have a website that display another website with iframe, and then i wanted to get the value from An input inside that iframe, but the catch is this input is not exist when the iframe  first load, is there any way to make a javascript code that constantly check if that input with specified id/class exist everytime (the iframe refresh) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout()` jQuery method to delay the execution of a function or/and use  `setInterval()` jQuery method to execute a function every a certain amount of time.

### setTimeout() example

> It will show a text 2 seconds after the window is completely loaded.

```js
$(window).on('load', function(){

   let msg = 'This appears after 2 seconds the window is completely loaded.'

 setTimeout(function(){
      $('#element-id').text(msg);
  }, 2000); 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body style="text-align:center">
  <div id="element-id" style="font-size:30px;color:black;width:300px">
  </div>
</body>
```

### setInterval() example

> It will append HTML code every 2 seconds

```js
$(window).on('load', function(){

     setInterval(function(){
          $('#element-id').append("<p>Do something every 2 seconds</p>");
      }, 2000); 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body style="text-align:center">
  <div id="element-id" style="font-size:15px;color:black;width:300px">
  </div>
</body>
```